# Сохранить файл из внутренних ресурсов приложения в ресурсы другого приложения

Tags: java, android

Я пыталась сохранить карту для майнкрафта (`.mcworld`) которая хранится в ресурсах моего приложения (`assets`) в ресурсы игры (`data/data/com.mojang/minecraftpe/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds`), чтобы приложение экспортировало карту в игру, но у меня ничего не выходит.

код манифеста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.worldmaps.testingformaps">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

код активности которая сохраняет:

```
package com.worldmaps.testingformaps;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button buton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    InputStream initialStream = new FileInputStream(
                            new File("src/main/assets/1.mcworld"));
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[initialStream.available()];
                    initialStream.read(buffer);
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(getExternalPath());
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private File getExternalPath() {
        return (new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "data/data/com.mojang/minecraftpe/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так это не работает. По умолчанию ресурсы приложения недоступны для других приложений. Есть 2 способа обхода:

1. Получить `root/su` права, тогда можно скопировать
2. В обоих приложениях зарегистрировать одинаковые атрибуты манифеста `android:sharedUserId="string"` и если подписи в обоих приложениях будут одинаковы, то вы сможете из одного приложения копировать/читать ресурсы другого приложения.

Comment: приложение майнкрафт, оно же не мое чтобы я манифест там изменяла, и я видела приложения с похожей реализацией

Comment: сохранить можно в папку /games/com.moajing/tmp/maps/ но потом нужно как то экспортировать карту в игру

Comment: 1) Есть 2 способа, оба указаны в ответе, насколько подходит тот или иной способ вам виднее.
2) Вполне допускаю, что майнкрафт умеет импортировать внешние карты сохраненные в `/games/com.moajing/tmp/maps/` - мне это неведомо. Экспорт во внешнюю папку из вашего приложения возможен - зависит от версии Android. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, да вы правы майнкрафт умеет это делать и мне удалось сохранить во внешний источник и чтобы запустить карту нужно просто запустить файл я делала это но это почему то не работает:

Comment: это: Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File( f.getPath()+fileName));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/minecraft");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);